# How to run Mojolicious appication under '/api' path( How to ignore some prefix in path )?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have application it works fine. But now we decide to move it under `/api` path. So I use [detour](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Route#detour)

```
my $r = $self->routes;

# Application is always under /api/v1, /api/v2 etc. path
$r =  $r->any( '/api/:api', [ api => qr/v\d+/ ] )->detour( 'MyApp' );

$r->get( '/users/me' )->to( 'user#show_me' );
```

But after this nothing works. Request to `site.domain/api/v1` cause application to fall into endless loop.

There is also [Mojolicious::Plugin::Mount](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Plugin/Mount) but it only useful to [mount another one application](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Application-embedding) under specified route.

[This](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Mount-applications) guide also does not resolve problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line should be fixed:

```
# Application is always under /api/v1, /api/v2 etc. path
$r =  $r->any( '/api/:api', [ api => qr/v\d+/ ] )->partial( 1 )
```

**Update**
As it was [documented](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Route#partial):

> Route has no specific end, remaining characters will be captured in path.

If you run `myapp.pl routes -v` you will see:

```
/api/:api        .D..  *        apiapi       ^\/api/((?^:v\d+))
   +/users/me    ....  GET      usersme      ^\/users\/me/?(?:\.([^/]+))?$
```

When request come it will be checked against this regex:

```
^\/api/((?^:v\d+))\/users\/me/?(?:\.([^/]+))?$
```

Where only `/users/me` will be captured in the `path`